# Grunt replace CDN is not working on corporate proxy

Tags: proxy, gruntjs

I am using following code to replace the url from CDN to local, but when I am in the corporate network under proxy it doesn't work but when I run the same code under no proxy internet it works as expected can anybody helps me to resolve this problem as I am unable to test my code in my

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

 var rewriteModule = require('http-rewrite-middleware');
 
 // Project configuration.
 grunt.initConfig({
     pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
     connect: {
      server: {
    options: {
     port: 9001,
     livereload: true,
     middleware: function (connect, options) {
                     // Setup the proxy
                     var middlewares = [require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest];
 
                     // RewriteRules support
                     middlewares.push(rewriteModule.getMiddleware([
                        //rewrite url for SSI includes on UI elements
                        //{from: '^index.html$', to: '/.tmp/index.html'},
                        {from: '^/app/(.*).html$', to: '/.tmp/$1.html'}
                     ]));
 
                     if (!Array.isArray(options.base)) {
                         options.base = [options.base];
                     }
 
                     var directory = options.directory || options.base[options.base.length - 1];
                     options.base.forEach(function (base) {
                         // Serve static files.
                         middlewares.push(connect.static(base));
                     });
 
                     // Make directory browse-able.
                     middlewares.push(connect.directory(directory));
 
                     return middlewares;
                 }
    },
    proxies: [
                 {
                     context: ['/templates', '/css', '/images'],
                     host: 'wwwtest.google.com',
                     port: 80,
                     https: false,
                     changeOrigin: false
                 },
                 {
                     context: ['/userCal', '/commonDataCal'],
                     host: 'wwwtest.google.com',
                     port: 443,
                     https: true,
                     changeOrigin: false
                 }
             ]
      }
     },
     ssi: {
      options: {
        cache: 'all',
        baseDir: '.'
      },
      ui: {
       files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: '.tmp',
     src: ['index.html', 'development.html'],
     dest: '.tmp/',
     ext: '.html'
          }]
      }
  },
     replace: {
   CDN: {
    src: ['app/index.html','app/development.html'],
    dest: '.tmp/',
    replacements: [{
                from: 'images.google.com',
                to: 'localhost:9001'
    }]
   }
  },
  watch: {
            files: ['**/*.html'],
   tasks: ['replace:CDN', 'ssi']
        },
        clean: {
         build: {
          src: ['.tmp']
         }
        },
        jshint: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'app/**/*.js'],
            options: {
             // options here to override JSHint defaults
             globals: {
              jQuery: true,
              console: true,
              module: true,
              document: true
             }
            }
        }
    });

 // Load the plugin that provides the above task.
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-connect-proxy');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-text-replace');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ssi');
 
 // Default task(s).
 grunt.registerTask('default', []);
 grunt.registerTask('server', ['replace:CDN', 'ssi', 'configureProxies:server', 'connect:server', 'watch']);
 //you can call the following tasks directly
 //grunt jshint
 //grunt clean

};
```

Comment: your server isn't reachable right? try changing `localhost:9001` to `0.0.0.0:9001`

Comment: I am able to access my server, but I am unable to pull some resources from internet as there is a corporate porxy.